# ボタンの読込先を個別に管理したい

Tags: php

こんにちは

require_onceでクラスを読み込めると思うのですが、

require_onceが多数あるとどれか一個を読み込ませることはできませんよね。

例えば、 
require_once(DIR . '/functions.php'); 
①require_once(DIR . '/autoload3.php'); 
②require_once(DIR . '/autoload2.php');

このようになっていたとします。

（A）あるリンクの際には②を読み込んでほしい（①は読み込む必要がない） 
（B）あるリンクの際には①を読み込んでほしい（②は読み込んで欲しくない）

こういった時（A）を行うとエラーが出てしまいます。

どうすればいいんでしょうか？？

Comment: どのようにして(A)を行ったのか、お試しになったソースコードとエラーメッセージを質問文に追記していただけませんか？（質問文の下にある「[edit]」でいつでも再編集が行えます）

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/26059

Answer (score 0):

PHPでは、どのアドレスで呼ばれたか（またはパラメータに何が指定されたか）が分かるので、
それを使ってif文で分ければ良いのではないでしょうか。

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == 'Aのアドレス')
  require_once(DIR . '/autoload2.php');
else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == 'Bのアドレス')
  require_once(DIR . '/autoload3.php');
```